# Make a range request with a custom date field on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date

I have this weird field in my MongoDB which acts as a date field but is just a regular text field.

It's values are like this:

- 03-Mar-2012
- 23-Feb-2013

Do you see any chance to do a date range like query on these values? For example I need to query everything between 1st of January 2011 and 3rd of March 2011.

I tried with $gte and $lte but the sorting doesn't work here.

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Is converting it to a timestamp understood by mongo out of the question?

Comment: The obvious solution would be to store it as a date. Otherwise you could use a regex, but it won't be very efficient.

Comment: I suppose I could add an additional date field based on the text value. Anyone knows how that would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do is to update the values to be an `ISODate()`, then the $gt and $lt will work properly.

```
function MonthToNr(month) {
    switch(month.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'jan': return '01';
        case 'feb': return '02';
        case 'mar': return '03';
        case 'apr': return '04';
        case 'may': return '05';
        case 'jun': return '06';
        case 'jul': return '07';
        case 'aug': return '08';
        case 'sep': return '09';
        case 'oct': return '10';
        case 'nov': return '11';
        case 'dec': return '12';
    }
}


db.test.find({date: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(o) {
    var parts = o.date.split("-");
    o.date = ISODate(parts[2] + '-' + MonthToNr(parts[1]) + '-' + parts[0]);
    db.test.save(o);
})
```